# Casting to void* with potentially sketchy behavior

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, void-pointers

I have been trying to fix a potentially sketchy use of `void*` casting in a task scheduling application for weeks now. Note that I am NOT getting a compiler error, but the scheduling program crashes after a few hours (for some unknown reason). Consider the following code snippets from the program:

In `main`:

```
CString* buffer = new CString(temp);
parameters.set("jobID", (void *) buffer);
runJob(parameters);
```

Also, `VGridTaskParam` class is as follows:

```
class VGridTaskParam{
    map<CString, void *> p; // maps from CString to a pointer that is not known 
public:
    void * get(CString name){
        return p[name]; // returns the map value of the name which is an unknown pointer 
    }
    void set(CString name, void * data){
        p[name] = data; // sets the mpa value given a particular key 
    }
};
```

Snippet of some work in `runJob(VGridTaskParam parameters)` function is:

```
void runJob(VGridTaskParam parameters)
{
        CString JIDstr; // job ID string 
//get job ID as CString
        CString* pJID = (CString*)parameters.get("jobID");
        JIDstr = CString(*pJID);
        delete pJID; ******************************
}
```

Some questions: does the last `delete` line (marked with several asterisks) delete the memory allocation created in the main program? Is my use of void* casting warranted in this situation. Note that whenever I run a job, I spawn a new thread. Can someone suggest a potential fix to this problem? What should I look at to fix this problem?

Comment: If it is crashing after a few hours and not right away, you're probably running out of memory, so your intuition about the `delete` is on point. It admittedly looks okay here, so I'm thinking the issue is somewhere else in `runJob` or a method it calls. Perhaps there is more memory allocation, or it's possible for your `CString*` to be deallocated another way, resulting in a double delete.

Comment: I can't say what the exact bug is, but I can say that dynamically allocating an object and requiring it to be manually deleted is asking for memory leaks.  My suggestion, if possible, would be to change the held-values-type of the parameters data structure from (void *) to unique_ptr<CString> (or even just to plain old stored-by-value Cstring), so that the required deletions are done automatically for you (and remove your explicit calls to delete, of course).  That will likely fix the problem.

Comment: I do not see any reason to use `void*` casts here, however, it doesn't seem they contribute to the crash. I'd suggest removing void* arithmetic from C++ programm, see if you need any dynamic memory management at all - possibly remove that as well. This will make the code cleaner and easier to reason about, so the bug could be found easier (if it still remains).

Comment: In your `get` and `set` methods, you will be creating holes in the map if `name` doesn't exist as a key.  The `std::map::operator[ ]` creates an entry if it doesn't exist already.  Instead, use `map::find()` or `map::count()` to determine if the item exists.

Answer (score 1):

> does the last `delete` line (marked with several asterisks) delete the memory allocation created in the main program?

Yes.

> Is my use of `void*` casting warranted in this situation?

No, that is superfluous. Any pointer can be cast to `void*` without the explicit cast.

> Can someone suggest a potential fix to this problem? What should I look at to fix this problem?

I can't suggest a fix without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I see two things that looks a bit surprising to me.

1) runJob takes parameters of type VGridTaskParam by value. Maybe you want a reference instead. That can't explain the crash, though.

2) You never seem to remove anything from the map even though you delete the memory associated with the pointer. So there is a risk that you'll use the pointer value later on. Either as a dereference or as a double delete.

3) You don't implement any check for the key being present in the map.

Answer (score 1):

A few possible issues:

what will happen if you write twice to same key? This will cause a memory leak. 
there are few possible solutions, like:

```
void set(CString name, void * data){
    if(p[name]!=NULL) 
      delete p[name]; 
    p[name] = data; // sets the mpa value given a particular key 
}
```

Another thing: Are you running multi-threaded or single threaded? for multi-threaded you should synchronize the get and set methods to prevent pointer changes in a middle of action.

And finally, what happen if key not found? you should check the returned pointer. also remove from the set or null it after usage.

```
void runJob(VGridTaskParam parameters)
{
    CString JIDstr; // job ID string 
    //get job ID as CString
    CString* pJID = (CString*)parameters.get("jobID");
    if(pJID){
       parameters.set("jobID",NULL);
       JIDstr = CString(*pJID);
       delete pJID; ******************************
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `delete` is correct. It deletes an allocated block of memory of the size of the pointer's type at the pointer's address. So when you allocate a `CString` with `new` you will `delete` the exact same amount of memory.

The hang up is when you delete *unallocated* memory. There are several ways I could see this happening in your current code:

1. `runJob` requests an key not in the `map` (this will return a default initialized `CString*` as the newly created value.)
2. You call `runJob` on a previously deleted item in the `map` (this value would already be deallocated and deleting it again would be illegal.)
3. We can't see all your code but if there is the potential to `delete` these pointers elsewhere there could also be a double cleanup problem there.

---

You should code your map more defensively, for example:

const void* get(const CString& name) const {
        return p.find(name) == p.cend() ? nullptr : p[name]; // returns the map value of the name which is an unknown pointer 
    }

```
void set(const CString& name, void* data) {
    void* toOverwrite = get(name);

    if(toOverwrite != nullptr) {
        delete toOverwrite;
    }
    p[name] = data; // sets the mpa value given a particular key 
}

void remove(const CString& name) {
    if(p.find(name) != p.end()) {
        p.erase(name);
    }
}
```

In your function you'd need to change to testing if the return of `get` was a `nullptr` before operating on the result, and rather than `delete` you'd need to call `remove`. This keeps all modification of `p` local to the class, thereby guaranteeing correct maintenance of the `map`.